# Highcharts IE8 - Error on page

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, highcharts

**Highcharts JS Version:** 3.0.3
**Broswer:** Internet Explorer 8
**Reference URL:** http://jsfiddle.net/aDCXR/1/show/

**Problem:**
When the cursor touches any of the bar graph charts (and I assume all charts) and then back on to the html page. (Mouseout/off of the Highcharts), I get the following error only in IE 8.

> Message: Object doesn't support this property or method Line: 4 Char:
>   8558 Code: 0 URI: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/j ...
>   ery.min.js

From what I have read online this is a bug inside the Highcharts JS library.

***Does anyone know of a fix so the IE8 will not produce this error?***

The code below is only for stackoverflow requirements.

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Combination chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Bananas', 'Plums']
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    var s;
                    if (this.point.name) { // the pie chart
                        s = ''+
                            this.point.name +': '+ this.y +' fruits';
                    } else {
                        s = ''+
                            this.x  +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                    return s;
                }
            },
            labels: {
                items: [{
                    html: 'Total fruit consumption',
                    style: {
                        left: '40px',
                        top: '8px',
                        color: 'black'
                    }
                }]
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'column',
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
            }, {
                type: 'column',
                name: 'John',
                data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6]
            }, {
                type: 'column',
                name: 'Joe',
                data: [4, 3, 3, 9, 0]
            }, {
                type: 'spline',
                name: 'Average',
                data: [3, 2.67, 3, 6.33, 3.33],
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
                    fillColor: 'white',
                    symbol: 'url(http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
                }
            }, {
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Total consumption',
                data: [{
                    name: 'Jane',
                    y: 13,
                    color: '#4572A7' // Jane's color
                }, {
                    name: 'John',
                    y: 23,
                    color: '#AA4643' // John's color
                }, {
                    name: 'Joe',
                    y: 19,
                    color: '#89A54E' // Joe's color
                }],
                center: [100, 80],
                size: 100,
                showInLegend: false,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is not related to highcharts, but with jquery. You'll need to update the version you're using (sample you have provided was 1.7.2), the latest version of jquery is 1.9.1 and that should take care of it.

Comment: Also dont update jquery to 2.XX, it does not support IE 8 and lower.

Comment: @no1uknow - Not asking for the points, but make sure you check off "Answered" so people know that a question has been answered. This is in relation to all the previous questions you have asked as well - noticed you haven't done it for any of them.

Comment: @Duniyadnd: Thanks Again! I didn't know to do check the check to make it green. Had too google for it... Amazingly I use Stackoverflow all the time but never had to ask questions and have not accumulated enough points to vote... Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in Highcharts also, so that it now works with older jQuery versions as announced. Though it is of course recommended that you use the latest jQuery. See https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2161.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but what you are referring to is another mouseout bug that was fixed in the Highcharts JS Lib. This issue was a problem with jQuery 1.7.1 as Duniyadnd discoved above. Upgrading to 1.9.1 jQuery fixes this issue. Again thanks for all the post this completely made my day!